# Power BI - Get JWT Token from Basic authentication

Tags: api, rest, authentication, jwt, powerbi

I'm getting a token from a REST API with Postman with this request:

```
URL:
https://www.wathever.com/fmi/data/v1/databases/sessions

Headers:
Authorization: Basic (binary generated by Postman)==
Postman-Token: <calculated when request is sent>
Content-Length: 0
Host: <calculated when request is sent>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

and I succesfully get a token:

```
{
    "response": {
        "token": "fff***********************3ecfc7f01a*****716"
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to get the token through Power BI with the following code (credential anonymous):

```
let server = "https://www.wathever.com/fmi/data/v1/databases/",
    database = "thedatabase",
    username = "username",
    psw = "apassword",
    url = server & database & "/sessions",
    bytes = Text.ToBinary(username & ":" & psw),
    encoded = Binary.ToText(bytes, BinaryEncoding.Base64),
    body = "",
    data = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
    [
        Headers = [
            #"Authorization"=("base64-encoded " &encoded),
            #"Content-Type"="application/json"
        ]
    ]))
in
    data
```

But I get the following error message:

> We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try
> again.

I also tried to connect with credential basic, without passing headers, but I get the following message:

> DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from
> 'https://www.wathever.com/fmi/data/v1/databases/sessions' (405):
> Method Not Allowed

Any idea of what I am missing?

Thanks!